# Catch event from Main Form

Tags: vb.net

I have a form that consists of a few tabs, each containing a user control. User controls need to know when the main form is closing so they can do some house keeping before closing.

How can I handle the FormClosing event which is thrown in the main form, in each of the UserControls?

Comment: create a method for the UC then call it on each in the form closing event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to dispose of unmanaged resources in your user control before closing, just have the user control implement the IDisposable pattern (and properly dispose of them within it...).

[Proper use of the IDisposable interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538060/proper-use-of-the-idisposable-interface)